# How to add array of object to the list

Tags: java

I have an array of object like
`A[] a;`

I also have a list of A like `List<A> b = new ArrayList<A>();`

I am wondering how to add `a` to `b`?

Comment: Do you want to add the _contents_ of `a` to `b`, or do you want to add the array itself to `b`?

Answer (score 7):

Just use the addAll() method with Arrays.asList() as argument:

```
b.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
```

Comment: Looks like you came up with the exact same answer as mine, but you posted 2 minutes later ;-) Sadly, you got more ups out of it :p

Comment: This solution is more expensive and more complex than ABCD's solution.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
b.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate the array and add each element

```
for( A element : a ) { 
    b.add( element ) 
}
```

Comment: +1 Sometimes keeping it simple is best. Nothing difficult here

Comment: I would advice against writing a custom loop, but for reusing an existing and easily understable generic building block (method).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are adding the contents of `a` to `b`, you would want to use `Collections.addAll(b, a);`

Comment: This solution is better than most other here, since it removes one conversion step (array -> list)

Answer (score 2):

[`list.addAll(Arrays.asList());`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

For example :

```
b.addAll(Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly"));
```

Comment: This will convert a from an array to a list but not add it to b.

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<A> b = new ArrayList<A>();
 b.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
```